# Mockito - Desired returned mock object not being used in class-under-test (CUT)

Tags: java, junit, dependency-injection, mockito

I'm trying to get a handle on Mockito and have a situation where I'd like to use a mock object from within the class-under-test (CUT) but it does not appear to be working.  I'm pretty sure I'm approaching the solution incorrectly.  Here's some code:

*CUT:*

```
public class TestClassFacade {

  // injected via Spring
  private InterfaceBP bpService;

  public void setBpService(InterfaceBP bpService) {

      this.bpService = bpService;
  }

  public TestVO getTestData(String testString) throws Exception {

    bpService = BPFactory.getSpecificBP();

    BPRequestVO bpRequestVO = new BPRequestVO();

    InterfaceBPServiceResponse serviceResponse = bpService.getProduct(bpRequestVO);

    if (serviceResponse.getMessage().equalsIgnoreCase("BOB")) {

        throw new Exception();

    } else {

        TestVO testVO = new TestVO();
    }

    return testVO;
  }

}
```

*Spring Configuration:*

```
<bean id="testClass" class="com.foo.TestClassFacade">

   <property name="bpService" ref="bpService" />

</bean>

<bean id="bpService" class="class.cloud.BPService" />
```

*Mockito Test Method:*

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class BaseTest {

    @Mock BPService mockBPService;
    @InjectMocks TestClassFacade mockTestClassFacade;

    String testString = "ThisIsATestString";
    BPRequestVO someBPRequestVO = new BPRequestVO();
    InterfaceBPServiceResponse invalidServiceResponse = new BPServiceResponse();

    @Test (expected = Exception.class)
    public void getBPData_bobStatusCode_shouldThrowException() throws Exception {

        invalidServiceResponse.setMessage("BOB");

        when(mockBPService.getProduct(someBPRequestVO)).thenReturn(invalidServiceResponse);

        mockTestClassFacade.getTestData(testString);

        verify(mockBPService.getProduct(someBPRequestVO));
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is verify that the "if" conditional portion of the CUT (throwing the Exception) is being invoked in the case of a "BOB" message string being returned from the response of the 3rd party class (BPService).  However, what's happening is that the "invalidResponse" object that I am trying to return in the "when" statement above isn't actually being returned when I run my mockTestClassFacade in the line below it.  Instead, the

```
InterfaceBPServiceResponse serviceResponse = bpService.getProduct(bpRequestVO);
```

line in the real method is being invoked and the "serviceResponse" is being used during my test.

**How do I get my mockTestClassFacade to use my "invalidServiceResponse" in this situation?**

Thanks a lot...if anything isn't clear please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in `bpService = BPFactory.getSpecificBP();`.

You're mocking and injecting `InterfaceBP` into `TestClassFacade`, but inside the method `getTestData` you're creating a new `InterfaceBP` from `BPFactory`.

So when testing, you're not actually using the mock, but a different object.

If `InterfaceBP` is created and injected by Spring, you shouldn't need a factory to get an instance.

Comment: Hmmm...I see what you mean.  Here's the problem though:  BPService (both the interface and the implementation) and BPFactory are both in a 3rd party jar that I don't have access to alter.

Comment: Ok...I understand what you suggested now.  It actually doesn't matter about those 3rd party classes at all.  All I have to do is simply remove the *BPFactory.getSpecificBP()* line of code completely.  I did that and now the test class is actually injecting the bpService as I wanted.  My *when* statement above still isn't being executed, but I'm going to mark this as answered because the original problem is now resolved.  

Thank you Khalid!

Comment: You're welcome. Regarding `BPFactory.getSpecificBP()`, you can use Spring to get an instance from the factory method. See: [Instantiation with a static factory method](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-class-static-factory-method)

Comment: Excellent.  I was not aware of that either.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from the other answer, you need to mock the behavior of "BPFactory.getSpecificBP()", but Mockito won't let you mock static methods. You'll have to use PowerMock for this test.

Comment: Ah...I remember reading about that limitation.  Now I resolved the issue above by just bypassing the now unneeded BPFactory, but thank you for a solution on how to approach this issue if that wasn't an option!